# Column of the max for each row in a matrix

Tags: julia

Consider the matrix:

```
M = [1.0 2.0 3.0; 5.0 4.0 3.0; 1.0 100.0 12.0]
```

I want to get column of the max value in each row.
So it should be:

```
col = [3; 1; 2]
```

, since

```
M[1,3] -> 3.0;
M[2,1] -> 5.0;
M[3,2] -> 100.00;
```

In Octave it is easy to achieve:

```
[max, col] = max(M,[],2)
```

, where col=[3;2;1].

In Julia I can find only `findmax` function which returns an absolute index of the max element for each row.
So it would be:

```
max, aindx = findmax(M,2)
```

, where aindx=[7,2,6]

M[7] = 3.0; M[2] = 5.0; M[6] = 100;

Where to find Julia equivelent for Octave max(M,[],2)?

My current workaround:

```
max, aindx = findmax(M, 2);
msize=size(M);
col = zeros(msize[1], 1);
for i=1:msize[1] 
  _, col[i] = ind2sub(msize,aindx[i]);
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Julia's `findmax` is more flexible than Octave's `max`: you can find the maximum over multiple dimensions at once. As a consequence, it returns a linear index.

As you've noted, you can use `ind2sub` to compute whatever index(es) you want. If you use this a lot, you might want to define your "workaround" as a function to make it convenient to use. You can put that function in your `.juliarc.jl` if you want to make sure it's always available.

Comment: Thank you @tholy. I will follow your advice and I'll put the code into the .juliarc.jl. I assume, that my code is not so bad, and you would do it more or less the same.

Comment: I assume that there is no equivalent for Octave `max(M,[],2)` (what I expected) and I treat your answer as a solution.